# How can I use Coffeescript 'this' from within jQuery $.bind()?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

When using classes in Coffeescript, I've stumbled upon a major problem, let me illustrate

```
class Bet
  constructor: () ->

  placeBet: ->
    $('#chips > div').bind 'click', ->
      amount = $(this).attr 'id'
      pile = $(this)
      switch amount
        when "ten" then this.bet pile, amount #This line causes a problem

  bet: (pile, amount) ->
    alert 'betting!'
```

The call to **this.bet** above generates the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'bet'**

So, currently the instance method of my class is not being called,
How can I correctly call the **bet** method of my class without it colliding with the jQuery selector's this (Which is what I suppose is happening now)?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can't you just set `this` to another variable before the jQuery stuff? `var myself = this;` and then use `myself.bet`

Comment: Just a side note, but you should really be caching `$(this)` if you're using it more than once.

Comment: @Josh Do you mean assigning $(this) to a variable, and then access everything I need through it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Bet
  constructor: () ->

  placeBet: ->
    that = this
    $('#chips > div').bind 'click', ->
      amount = $(this).attr 'id'
      pile = $(this)
      switch amount
        when "ten" then that.bet pile, amount #This line causes a problem

  bet: (pile, amount) ->
    alert 'betting!'
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with coffeescript. Obviously, I would use ```var``` in regular JavaScript, but I didn't see any ```var```'s in the OP's code, so I wasn't sure if it exists in coffeescript.

Comment: Awesome, this works fine. May I ask one thing? is it proper to do it this way? or is there a better pattern to accomplish this? Maybe even Coffeescript has a syntax to reference itself(the class)? I'm 100% new to Coffeescript, so I'm just wondering... It is a great solution nonetheless. Maybe I had expected it'd be harder to solve this.

Comment: This is a very common practice in JavaScript. You can name the variable something besides ```that```. I've also seen ```me```, ```self```, ```_this```, etc.

Comment: Great then! Thank you very much for this, Mr. Bradley.

Comment: On my system, bound functions in coffeescript (eg, `() => ...` compiles down to use `_this`, so I'd avoid using that personally...

Answer (score 44):

Another solution is to use the CoffeeScript fat-arrow in the click event handler then your scope would be the same as if you were inside the placeBet function. You would then use `e.currentTarget` to get a reference to the target object instead of using `$(this)`

```
class Bet
  constructor: ->

  placeBet: ->
    $('#chips > div').bind 'click', (e) =>
      target = $(e.currentTarget)
      amount = target.attr 'id'

      switch amount
        when "ten" then @bet target, amount #This line causes a problem

  bet: (pile, amount) ->
    alert 'betting!'
```

Comment: This one is pretty Cool Sandro! I need to review how the fat arrow works though, as of now it still gives me headaches to understand it.
Thank you for this solution!

Comment: +1 Thank you, I was still used the old way of $.proxy-ing this into the function call.

Answer (score 0):

You script turns into this:

```
var Bet;

Bet = (function() {

  function Bet() {}

  Bet.prototype.placeBet = function() {
    return $('#chips > div').bind('click', function() {
      var amount, pile;
      amount = $(this).attr('id');
      pile = $(this);
      switch (amount) {
        case "ten":
          return this.bet(pile, amount); //<< you cannot do this!!!
      }
    });
  };

  Bet.prototype.bet = function(pile, amount) {
    return alert('betting!');
  };

  return Bet;

})();
```

---

What you need is a reference to `_self` which is is the `Bet` object:

```
class Bet
  constructor: () ->

  placeBet: ->
    _self = this
    $('#chips > div').bind 'click', ->
      amount = $(this).attr 'id'
      pile = $(this)
      switch amount
        when "ten" then _self.bet pile, amount #This line causes a problem

  bet: (pile, amount) ->
    alert 'betting!'
```