# Can't call instance method in java/coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm new to coffeescript and javascript. I've written following example.
This fails when `bar` is called.

```
class FooBar
  constructor: ->
    @cleanBinding()
    @addBinding()
    @foo

  addBinding: ->
    $(document).on 'click', '.foo', @foo
    $(document).on 'input', 'input#bar', @bar

  cleanBinding: ->
    $(document).off 'click', '.foo'
    $(document).off 'input', 'input#bar'

  foo: ->
    alert('foo')

  bar: (e) ->
    @foo()
    e.preventDefault()

@FooBar = FooBar
```

The call `@foo` within `bar` gets compiled to `this.foo()` in javascript. However, this **fails** because `this.foo` is undefined. The strange `this` is a link, `<a href>`. Can someone help me, to figure out, what's going on?

Comment: `FooBar` is created in the dispatcher with `new FooBar()`. The call to `.foo()` happens in `.bar()`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658222/how-can-i-use-coffeescript-this-from-within-jquery-bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out what your problem is.

The real problem is how you're registering your event handlers:

```
$(document).on 'click', '.foo', @foo
```

because `@foo` here is just a `FooBar::foo` function without any context.

You have two ways of fixing it.

---

First, you may explicitly bind `@foo` with `this`, which is the common JS solution:

```
$(document).on 'click', '.foo', @foo.bind this
```

---

Second, you may use CoffeeScript fat arrow operator `=>` when defining your methods:

```
class FooBar
  constructor: ->
    @cleanBinding()
    @addBinding()
    @foo

  addBinding: ->
    $(document).on 'click', '.foo', @foo
    $(document).on 'input', 'input#bar', @bar

  cleanBinding: ->
    $(document).off 'click', '.foo'
    $(document).off 'input', 'input#bar'

  foo: =>
    alert('foo')

  bar: (e) =>
    @foo()
    e.preventDefault()
```

It'll tell CoffeeScript compiler to `.bind()` those methods automatically when new instance of `FooBar` class is created.